# How to Parse Nested Json using Spark and Scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Visitors of an eCommerce site browse multiple products during their visit. All visit data of a visitor is consolidated in a JSON document containing vistor Id and a list of product Ids, along with an interest attribute containing value of interest expressed by visitor in a product.  Here are two example records - rec1 and rec2 containing visit data of two visitors v1 and v2:

```
val rec1: String = """{
    "visitorId": "v1",
    "products": [{
         "id": "i1",
         "interest": 0.68
    }, {
         "id": "i2",
         "interest": 0.42
    }]
}"""

val rec2: String = """{
    "visitorId": "v2",
    "products": [{
         "id": "i1",
         "interest": 0.78
    }, {
         "id": "i3",
         "interest": 0.11
    }]
}"""

val visitsData: Seq[String] = Seq(rec1, rec2)

val productIdToNameMap = Map("i1" -> "Nike Shoes", "i2" -> "Umbrella", "i3" -> "Jeans")
```

Given the collection of records (visitsData) and a map (productIdToNameMap) of product Ids and their names:

1. Write the code to enrich every record contained in visitsData with the name of the product. The output should be another sequence with all the original JSON documents enriched with product name. Here is the example output.

   ```
   val output: Seq[String] = Seq(enrichedRec1, enrichedRec1)
   ```

   where enrichedRec1 has value -

   ```
   """{
       "visitorId": "v1",
       "products": [{
            "id": "i1",
            "name": "Nike Shoes",
            "interest": 0.68
       }, {
            "id": "i2",
            "name": "Umbrella",
            "interest": 0.42
       }]
   }"""

   And enrichedRec2 has value -
   """{
       "visitorId": "v2",
       "products": [{
            "id": "i1",
            "name": "Nike Shoes",
            "interest": 0.78
       }, {
            "id": "i3",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "interest": 0.11
       }]
   }"""
   ```

Comment: check my answer which does exactly same as you expected. but raise another question for each requirement. i deleted other questions since it will fall under "too broad" category and is prone to close the question !!!

Answer (score 0):

Example of method to parse json with scala and give the result in case class

```
 /** ---------------------------------------
        * 
               {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "field1": "value",
                    "field2": [
                      {
                        "field21": "value",
                        "field22": "value"
                      },
                      {
                        "field21": "value",
                        "field22": "value"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }*/

  case class elementClass(element1 : String, element2 : String)
  case class outputDataClass(field1 : String, exampleClassData : List[elementClass])

  def multipleMapJsonParser(jsonDataFile : String) : List[outputDataClass] = {

    val JsonData : String = Source.fromFile(jsonDataFile).getLines.mkString
    val jsonFormatData = JSON.parseFull(JsonData)
      .map{
        case json : Map[String, List[Map[String,Any]]] => json("fields").map(
          jsonElem =>
            outputDataClass(jsonElem("field1").toString,
              jsonElem("field2").asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,String]]].map{
                case element : Map[String,String] => elementClass(element("field21"),element("field22"))
              })
        )
      }.get

    jsonFormatData

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do enrichment of the json

```
     package com.examples

  import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}


  object EnrichJson extends App {

    private[this] implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import spark.implicits._

    val rec1: String =
      """{
      "visitorId": "v1",
      "products": [{
           "id": "i1",
           "interest": 0.68
      }, {
           "id": "i2",
           "interest": 0.42
      }]
  }"""

    val rec2: String =
      """{
      "visitorId": "v2",
      "products": [{
           "id": "i1",
           "interest": 0.78
      }, {
           "id": "i3",
           "interest": 0.11
      }]
  }"""

    val visitsData: Seq[String] = Seq(rec1, rec2)
    val productIdToNameMap = Map("i1" -> "Nike Shoes", "i2" -> "Umbrella", "i3" -> "Jeans")
    val dictionary = productIdToNameMap.toSeq.toDF("id", "name")
    val rddData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(visitsData)


    dictionary.printSchema()


    println("for spark version >2.2.0")

    var resultDF = spark.read.json(visitsData.toDS)
      .withColumn("products", explode(col("products")))
      .selectExpr("products.*", "visitorId")
      .join(dictionary, Seq("id"))
    resultDF.show
    resultDF.printSchema()
    convertJson(resultDF)

    println("for spark version <2.2.0")
    resultDF = spark.read.json(rddData)
      .withColumn("products", explode(col("products")))
      .selectExpr("products.*", "visitorId")
      .join(dictionary, Seq("id"))
    // .withColumn("products", explode(col("products")))
    resultDF.show
    resultDF.printSchema()
    convertJson(resultDF)

    /**
      * convertJson : converts the data frame to json string
      * @param resultDF
      */
    private def convertJson(resultDF: DataFrame) = {
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, _}

      val x: DataFrame = resultDF
        .groupBy("visitorId")
        .agg(collect_list(struct("id", "interest", "name")).as("products"))
      x.show
      println(x.toJSON.collect.mkString)
    }
  }
```

Result :

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

for spark version >2.2.0
+---+--------+---------+----------+
| id|interest|visitorId|      name|
+---+--------+---------+----------+
| i1|    0.68|       v1|Nike Shoes|
| i2|    0.42|       v1|  Umbrella|
| i1|    0.78|       v2|Nike Shoes|
| i3|    0.11|       v2|     Jeans|
+---+--------+---------+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- interest: double (nullable = true)
 |-- visitorId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+---------+--------------------+
|visitorId|            products|
+---------+--------------------+
|       v2|[[i1, 0.78, Nike ...|
|       v1|[[i1, 0.68, Nike ...|
+---------+--------------------+

{"visitorId":"v2","products":[{"id":"i1","interest":0.78,"name":"Nike Shoes"},{"id":"i3","interest":0.11,"name":"Jeans"}]}{"visitorId":"v1","products":[{"id":"i1","interest":0.68,"name":"Nike Shoes"},{"id":"i2","interest":0.42,"name":"Umbrella"}]}
for spark version <2.2.0
+---+--------+---------+----------+
| id|interest|visitorId|      name|
+---+--------+---------+----------+
| i1|    0.68|       v1|Nike Shoes|
| i2|    0.42|       v1|  Umbrella|
| i1|    0.78|       v2|Nike Shoes|
| i3|    0.11|       v2|     Jeans|
+---+--------+---------+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- interest: double (nullable = true)
 |-- visitorId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+---------+--------------------+
|visitorId|            products|
+---------+--------------------+
|       v2|[[i1, 0.78, Nike ...|
|       v1|[[i1, 0.68, Nike ...|
+---------+--------------------+

{"visitorId":"v2","products":[{"id":"i1","interest":0.78,"name":"Nike Shoes"},{"id":"i3","interest":0.11,"name":"Jeans"}]}{"visitorId":"v1","products":[{"id":"i1","interest":0.68,"name":"Nike Shoes"},{"id":"i2","interest":0.42,"name":"Umbrella"}]}
```